# InputTransparent = true is not working in Frame?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

A simple page content: a out layout that contains a frame and some buttons. The frame contains a stackLayout, inside the stacklayout are some labels.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="outLayout">
        <Frame  x:Name="frame"  
                HasShadow="True"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                OutlineColor="Gray"
                Margin="16,0,16,0">
            <StackLayout x:Name="innerLayout" BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Label Text="Testing" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" InputTransparent="True"/>
                <Label Text="Testing" FontSize="Small" InputTransparent="True"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
        <Button Text="Frame handle tap event" Clicked="Button_Clicked"></Button>
        <Button Text="inner Layout handle tap event" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"></Button>
        <Button Text="out layout handle tap event" Clicked="Button_Clicked_2" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Code-behind I have a TapGesture event, if some view clicked, simply log a message.

```
 public TestInputTransparent()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        var tapGesture = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGesture.Tapped += TapGesture_Tapped;

        innerLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
        frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
        outLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGesture);
    }

    private void TapGesture_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is StackLayout) {
            Debug.WriteLine(" stacklayout Tapped");
        } else if (sender is Frame) {
            Debug.WriteLine( " frame Tapped");
        } 
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        innerLayout.InputTransparent = true;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        innerLayout.InputTransparent = false;
    }

    private void Button_Clicked_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frame.InputTransparent = true;
    }
```

My expectation is that any tap event will be handled by the out stackLayout, no matter the tap event is received by the children of the out stackLayout.

When I click the button "Frame handle tap event", I set the `innerLayout.InputTransparent = true;` so tap event will handled by the frame. I could set it back by clicking the second button. But when I set `frame.InputTransparent = true;`, tap event is still stay in the frame element. Frame will not hand in to the out stackLayout. Why? Is Frame a special case?

Comment: On what platform? Or all? It looks a bit like [this bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59506)

Comment: On Android. Strong it works with stackLayout, but only not with Frame.